# Error while Installing hive on windows

Tags: hadoop, hive, installation

Im trying to install hive on windows.I'm almost complete my install.But while staring hive command im getting the below error.

```
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Connection is already closed.
```

Here's my hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveusera</value>
<description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>hivepassword</value>
<description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
 <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
 <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I'm using MySQL as the backend for my hive

I tried with all possible solution deleting *.lck,Coping the mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin to the /lib

Nothing helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer.I'm actually missing the schema for my meta store in MySQL. Im now add it and works fine :)